# Numpy generate random array based on another array's values

Tags: numpy, random

I have 2 numpy arrays, `a` and `b`. Here:

```
a = np.random.randint(501, size=100)
```

How can I randomly generate array `b` of size 100 in a vectorized way such that:

1. `b[i] > a[i]` for all values of `i`.
2. Each value of `b` lies between `[0, 501)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numpy` supports array parameters. You can use `a` as the lower boundary:

```
>>> rng = np.random.default_rng()
>>> 
>>> a = rng.integers(501,size=10)
>>> 
>>> a
array([ 82,  95, 463, 367, 257, 296, 449, 473, 202, 468])
>>> 
>>> b = rng.integers(a,501)
>>> 
>>> b
array([104, 153, 476, 376, 366, 391, 458, 474, 470, 499])
```